# Static files with Express

Tags: css, express, static, pug, stylesheet

I am trying to link a stylesheet in a jade template, and am getting a 404. I have the exact path to the stylesheet, and have my app configured to serve up static files from my 'static' directory, but I am still getting a 404 ? Also why do static files need to be served up ? Why can't they just be linked to in your templates ?

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates')

app.listen('3000', function(){
    console.log('Running on port 3000');
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

// Routes

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.render('index')    
});

app.get('/blog:id', function(request, response){
    response.send('This is the blog page.')
})

app.get('/about', function(request, response){
    response.send('This is the about page.')
})
```

Jade template

```
html
    head
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="../../static/css/normalize.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7", crossorigin="anonymous")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css", integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r", crossorigin="anonymous")
    body
        div.hero(style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: blue")
            h1(style="color: white;") This is the landing page !
        script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js",   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=",   crossorigin="anonymous")
        script(src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js", integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS", crossorigin="anonymous")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your css file url relative to the static folder

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/normalize.css")
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it should be having a backslash in front of the link. did you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I just did with no luck.

Comment: When you use express.static( ), does that just allow you to reference static files from anywhere in the project using only the file path of the static file relative to the static folder ?

Comment: Yes, the way you have it set up the references should be relative to the static folder. See the first example here: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: What I know is that if you use `express.static('xxx', __dirname + '/static')`, you can access the file `'/static/file'` via `'http://host/xxx/file'`. Since you don't have the `'xxx'` in front, you can access to the file via `'http://host/file'`. Hope you get what I am trying to convey

Comment: Ahhh finally got it to work. I guess I needed my static directory in the same place as my app.js file where I have all my express configurations.